# Weak wifi signal Lenovo Yoga 500

Tags: wireless, 18.04, lenovo, iwlwifi

I have been using a Lenovo Yoga 500 laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 for over a year and, for some unknown reason, I recently started experiencing problems with my wifi connection. It may be related to some kernel upgrade, but I cannot guarantee it since I normally use a wired connection and did not realize immediately about this issue.

The problem is that all wifi signals (from different wireless networks) are found to be very weak. In order to connect, or even to detect them, I need to place the laptop close to the router. I do not experience this issue when I use Windows in the same laptop.

Output of uname -r:

```
4.15.0-46-generic
```

Output of lshw -class network:

```
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 Plus Bluetooth
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 99
       serial: 08:d4:0c:d4:49:50
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-46-generic firmware=29.1044073957.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:128 memory:d2200000-d2201fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 15
       serial: 54:ee:75:93:e1:97
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=147.156.160.216 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:17 ioport:c000(size=256) memory:d2104000-d2104fff memory:d2100000-d2103fff
```

Output of lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208BM [GeForce 920M] (rev a1)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 Plus Bluetooth (rev 99)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

Output of rfkill list all:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I tried installing the firmware from Intel (downloaded from https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html) but after copying the files to /lib/firmware I noticed no difference at all. In fact, I believe I did not do it properly, since I still run the version of the firmware that I had before, as I understand from this output of dmesg | grep -i firmware:

```
[    0.028000] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.088498] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    2.323888] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin (v1.26)
[   23.557242] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.1044073957.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   24.301855] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[   24.596957] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel firmware patch completed and activated
```

The one that I downloaded was version 14, not 29. I do not know whether this relevant or not, but wanted to mention it just in case.

I should also point out that a colleague of mine has exactly the same laptop, also with Ubuntu 18.04, with the same wireless controller and Linux kernel. However, he does not experience my problem.

Please, let me know if you need more information. Thanks a lot in advance.

EDIT: I updated the kernel to 4.15.0-47-generic and the problem persists. I also compared all my command outputs with my colleague's and they are exactly the same (besides 'link = yes' in his case, of course). I am about to upgrade the Ubuntu version to 18.10 to see whether that solves the problem, but I am not very optimistic...

EDIT 2: I confirm that upgrading to Ubuntu 18.10 did not help.

Comment: If you interrupt the boot process at the GRUB menu and boot into an earier kernel version, 4.15.0-44 perhaps, is the problem resolved? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Good point. I forgot to mention that I already tried that: the issue is present also when booting with 4.15.0-45.